# cannot convert sql/oracle database to system.data.entity.database

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to upgrade an application (from .net framework 2.0 to 4.71), and get errors as I can't convert sql/oracle databases to system.data.entity.database.

The code is as follows:

```
using EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;


public Database GetDatabase(string name)
    {
        UMiami.MedResearch.Core.ConnectionString str = this.Retrieve(name);
        if (str != null)
        {
            if (str.ProviderType == "SQL Server")
            {
                return new SqlDatabase(str.Value);
            }
            if (str.ProviderType == "Oracle")
            {
                return new OracleDatabase(str.Value);
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Connection string was not found.");
    }
```

The errors received are:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase' to 'System.Data.Entity.Database'

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet.OracleDatabase' to 'System.Data.Entity.Database'

The errors are only thrown if I set the solution for a Release configuration, and disappear if it's a Debug configuration. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the wrong base type `DataBase.

You are getting the `System.Data.Entity.Database` where it should be `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database`.

Try to remove the namespace `System.Data.Entity` and use `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data`, or specify the full namespace to `Database`.

```
using EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
// replace to the right namespace
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;


public Database GetDatabase(string name)
{
     UMiami.MedResearch.Core.ConnectionString str = this.Retrieve(name);
     if (str != null)
     {
         if (str.ProviderType == "SQL Server")
         {
             return new SqlDatabase(str.Value);
         }
         if (str.ProviderType == "Oracle")
         {
             return new OracleDatabase(str.Value);
         }
     }
     throw new Exception("Connection string was not found.");
}
```

Comment: Slight problem. That only works if I set it to a debug configuration. If I set it to Release, it throws the following error -  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary' (are you missing an assembly reference?)